Kids film about two or three boys and a magic necklace
I saw a movie when I was a kid on German tv. I don't know if it was originally German or some other language and then dubbed in German.
It was about two (or three, I can't remember) boys. One of them gets a weird necklace: a stone or metalic snowflake-looking thing. The necklace is broken somehow and the boy needs to find other pieces of the thing and return it to some sort of a princess or a witch. The stone/metalic "snowflake" has magical powers (I don't remember what exactly).
There's also one Gandalf-like person: tall and skinny older man dressed in a robe and funny looking hat (a flat one, reminded me of one that the Pope wears?).
To find the pieces of the magic necklace, the boys and the older man travel through time. I remember one scene when they travel about 20 years in the past and meet a young woman who turns out to be the boys' mother.
I can barely remember this movie, but I saw it in the 90s or early 2000s. It wasn't animated, the main boys were around 8 years old. It was in color.

Could be a tv show, Tajemnica Sagali (Das Geheimnis des Sagala). It's a Poland/Germany production from 1997. 
The boy finds a piece of a magic stone, Sagala. Then he finds another piece in his grandfather's house and joins the two pieces together. Accidentally uses the stone and turns his mother into a younger version of herself (a 9-10 year old to be exact).
Here's a picture of the stone

The older man is Jarpen - stone's guardian and he travels with the boys to find the rest of Sagala to bring boys' mother back to her normal age.

I don't remember anything about there being a princess/witch that the stone is supposed to be return to.
